# Struggling with Rails Wikiquote gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mediawiki-api, wikimedia

I am writing my first rails website and have come across a problem.  I want to show a "quote of the day" on the welcome page using the 'wikiquote' gem (http://hemanth.github.io/wikiquote-gem/).  I put it in the code below and thought it would work, but was mistaken.  The browser does not say there are any errors, but nothing shows up either.  Any thoughts?  Am I doing this utterly wrong?

in `welcome_controller.rb`

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end    

  def get_qod
    @qod = WikiQuote.get
  end
end
```

in `welcome/index.html.erb`

`<h3> <%= @qod.to_s %></h3>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You're doing it wrong.

if you want @qod to be available for index, you need to run it inside index.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @qod = WikiQuote.get
  end    

end
```

Alternatively you can outsource this method:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_quote, only: [:index]

  def index       
  end

  private 
    def get_quote
      @qod = WikiQuote.get
    end

end
```